# Puppet hiera and inherited classes

Tags: inheritance, puppet

Here is a Puppet class `s_mysql`:

```
class s_mysql ( $use_local_packages = false) {
  if ($use_local_packages) {
    notify { 'using local packages': }
  } else {
    notify { 'NOT using local packages': }
  }
  ... more ...
}
```

There is another class that inherits `s_mysql`:

```
class s_mysql::test inherits s_mysql {
  ... stuff ..
}
```

Here is a node that includes `s_mysql::test`:

```
node testserver1 { include s_mysql::test }
```

I have a YAML hiera data source for this server:

```
---
# testserver1.yaml
s_mysql::use_local_packages : true
```

I run the command-line version of hiera to ensure that the the hiera data value is correct:

```
% hiera s_mysql::use_local_packages ::hostname=testerver1
# outputs "true"
```

However, when I run Puppet on `testserver1` I get this error:

```
Could not find data item s_mysql::use_local_packages 
in any Hiera data file and no default supplied
```

Why does this not work?

Note: I am running Puppet 3.7.2.

Comment: the correct way to write what you want in hiera "s_mysql::use_local_packages: true"

Comment: what was the origin of the issue ? I'm facing the same problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32040999/hiera-3-puppet-4-2-cant-manage-empty-value-in-yaml-datasource