# Hiera 3 + Puppet 4.2 can't manage empty value in yaml datasource

Tags: puppet, hiera

I'm facing some issues to use Hiera 3 with Puppet 4.2.
When applying my puppet manifest using this command:

```
puppet apply environments/production/manifests/init.pp --hiera_config=hiera.yaml
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Function Call, Could not find data item myclass::ensure in any Hiera data file and no default supplied at /home/vagrant/temp/environments/production/manifests/init.pp:13:39 on node a
```

Here is the directory structure :

```
$ tree
.
├── environments
│   └── production
│       ├── config.yaml
│       └── manifests
│           └── init.pp
└── hiera.yaml
```

content of config.yaml:

```
$ cat hiera.yaml 
---
:backends:
  - yaml

:hierarchy:
  - config

:yaml:
  :datadir: environments/production
```

content of init.pp:

```
class myclass(
  $version                          = $myclass::params::version,
  $ensure                           = $myclass::params::ensure,
) inherits myclass::params {

  notify {"$version": }
  notify {"$ensure": }

}

class myclass::params {
  $version                          = hiera('myclass::version', '1.0.0')
  $ensure                           = hiera('myclass::ensure', 'running')
}

class {'myclass': }
```

content of hiera data source:

```
$ cat config.yaml
---
myclass::version: '1.0.0'
myclass::ensure:
```

Looks like Hiera can't handle empty values from a yaml data source and/or replace them by default value?

Comment: If you include a value there, does it work?

Comment: Yes, when a set a value for myclass::ensure it works

Comment: Why not just drop `myclass::ensure:` from your YAML then? Apparently, a `nil` value can actually get returned and stir trouble. This might be a bug.

Comment: @FelixFrank ensure is an optional parameter. The example i mentionned are a very simplified to reproduce the case. But my real manifests are more complicated and the Yaml contains much more parameters, each one can be optional.

Comment: What I'm saying is, don't include empty values in the hiera data if you want to fall back to the default. It might be safer to `#` comment out the line instead. FWIW, a `hiera()` call that specifies a default value (like `hiera('myclass::ensure', 'running')` in your example) should never fail like this. - As an aside, your `params` class can forgo the `hiera()` invocation and just do `$ensure = 'running'`. The `myclass` will pick up the Hiera value automatically thanks to [automatic data binding](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/hiera/1/puppet.html#automatic-parameter-lookup)

Comment: to the best of my knowledge the hiera look up function ignores empty values when doing the lookup.

Comment: I just ran into the same problem - someone had an empty value for a key in their yaml (as a placeholder) and I was trying to write a test and put a value in an rspec.yaml, but the higher ‘empty’ hierarchy value was used, and not the lower one with a value